# Plot Random and Jagged Parallel Lines

Tags: python, gnuplot, data-visualization

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I'm interested in an algorithm which can draw lines with some "entropy". That is, somewhat jagged or crooked. I was thinking of drawing a vector or random length, turning some slight random angle < n degrees, and repeating until I reached the end of the canvas. Then, I would draw a line parallel to that with similar entropy. Ultimately, I'm thinking this might have a moire effect.

Comment: Do you mean like splittin up each joining line into a poly with random number of segments, and and then random-offset each coordinate in between your actual datapoints? Or did you have something else in mind. Also, you question seems to start off as a question about a programming problem, and then goes off on a tangent. Are you asking for programming help, or for inspiration?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to describe what this artist does mathematically: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cL_f5QR29E